# Accessing Sharepoint list data in a normal HTML page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list

I am trying to create a simple HTML page where i wanted to display a list of items from a SharePoint list. Basically my JavaScript has to pull the data from SharePoint list and display in HTML page.

I have tried some sample from internet, nothing worked. Can anybody have any samples on this. Please help me to implement this.

Comment: This is too vague. Please ask a specific question (and provide sample code if possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Library for Sharepoint WebService](http://spservices.codeplex.com)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery.SPServices-0.5.4.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
<ul id="tasksUL"/>
```